# Add listener and value to multiple types of elements on the page

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, dom-events

I have multiple elements on the page including checkbox and textfield. I want to set their default value and add listener to them all. If they are a textfield, I want to add a `input` listener... if they are a checkbox, I want to add a `change` listener. This is what I have so far.

```
const settings = {
  'setting1': 2,
  'setting2': true,
  'setting3': 400,
  'setting4': true,
}

for (var prop in settings) {
    console.log(prop)
}
```

but it doesn't iterate over the object. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//You need to do something like this


const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
const checkboxs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for (input of inputs) {
    input.setAttribute('value', defaultValue);
    input.addEventListener('input', callbackFunction);
}

// just repeat the loop for the checkbox elements
```

Comment: I can't dynamically set values like this... values are in my object

Comment: you can do a loop through the object, inside of the loop of the elements!